# Playing mp4 video using FLVPlayback module?

Tags: actionscript-3, mp4, flvplayback

I link my mp4 video directly using video.source = "my.mp4" in AS3 and the link is not broken, but then player keeps on loading forever.

Any ideas?

TA

Comment: Is it a protected MP4 (eg downloaded from Apple iTunes) or digitally encrypted?

Comment: Flash Player version? And: is this the only mp4 that does not work?

Comment: flash v 11.11 and tried 3 different mp4s, none worked

Comment: Could you try if this works? http://blog.six4rty.ch/downloads/sampleH264.zip And: could you post the code you use to load it? Have you a public URL to see this thing in action?   :-)

Comment: AS3:
video.source = "http://codedoctrine.com/projects/media/WF109H.mp4";
video.play(); via FLVPlayback

Comment: What happens if you set a bufferTime?

Comment: i have tried sampleH264, didnt work :(

Comment: same with bufferTime, but movie loads, within screen i can see, just no video is shown. hmm worrying

Answer (score 2):

Got it, thanks guys.

Found out that all it needs is a simple video object and a NetConnection  instead of FLVPlayback.

Source:http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/hd_video_flash_player.html

Comment: FLVPlayback is pretty strict and won't allow query strings in the URL, which could prevent playback, in case anyone ran into that problem.